# Unbrewed Header Files

Tags: macos, ocaml, homebrew

I'll be taking a course at my university next semester in OCaml, so I've decided to install it in advance. To do this, I've installed Homebrew on my OS X. However, whenever I try to install opam I receive this error message:

Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:

```
/usr/local/include/libpng12/png.h
/usr/local/include/libpng12/pngconf.h
/usr/local/include/libpng14/png.h
/usr/local/include/libpng14/pngconf.h
/usr/local/include/libpng15/png.h
/usr/local/include/libpng15/pngconf.h
/usr/local/include/libpng15/pnglibconf.h
```

I've tried removing these files manually, but it says gives me an error message saying "Permission Denied." Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should think at least a little bit about how the files got there. You don't want to throw them away if they're useful.

If you're convinced you don't need them you can become super-user temporarily and remove them:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/local/include/libpng1[245] /tmp
```

Be *extremely* careful when typing this (or any) `sudo` line. You can mess things up very badly with your super powers.

When `sudo` asks for a password, type your own password.

This will only work if you are an "administrative" user of your Mac. There's always at least one administrative user.

What this does is move the files to the /tmp directory. If you decide you need them, you can move them back. Eventually you might want to throw them away completely.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

First run `brew doctor` if `brew` throws an error.

Second, if you get a `Permission Denied` error, make sure whatever you're doing is completely OK, (as in first run `brew doctor` and find the exact problem) and prepend `sudo` to your command (i.e. `rm` to `sudo rm`). Then enter your administrator password.

Third, and just to emphasize, **BE CAREFUL WITH `sudo`**. Make sure whatever you're doing is perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to remove the files.